# Writing from multiple RICH TEXT EDITORS into a RTF file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, rtf

I have a text-based application with 4 Rich Text Editors. When I hit my save button, contents from all these Rich Text Editors has to be saved into a single RTF file!!

Comment: I have tried to use stream but the file contains only data from the first RTE.

Comment: Show the *relevant* area of your code, such as where you are moving data into the stream and saving it.

Comment: RichTextBox1.SaveFile(userInput, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
userInput.WriteByte(13)

RichTextBox2.SaveFile(userInput, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
userInput.WriteByte(13)

RichTextBox3.SaveFile(userInput, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
userInput.WriteByte(13)

RichTextBox4.SaveFile(userInput, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
userInput.WriteByte(13)

userInput.Position = 0
RichTextTemp.LoadFile(userInput, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)

Seems to work fine when streamtype is plaintext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working, though not particularly elegant solution:

```
    Dim temprtb As New RichTextBox
    With temprtb
        .Select(temprtb.TextLength, 0)
        .SelectedRtf = RichTextBox1.Rtf
        .Select(temprtb.TextLength, 0)
        .SelectedRtf = RichTextBox2.Rtf
        .Select(temprtb.TextLength, 0)
        .SelectedRtf = RichTextBox3.Rtf
        .Select(temprtb.TextLength, 0)
        .SelectedRtf = RichTextBox4.Rtf
        .SaveFile("C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test.rtf")
    End With
```

It creates a new richtextbox, appends the contents of the existing richtextboxes, and saves the file.

EDIT A more elegant solution might be to put all the richtextboxes in a panel and loop through them:

```
    Dim temprtb As New RichTextBox
    For Each c As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is RichTextBox Then
            temprtb.Select(temprtb.TextLength, 0)
            temprtb.SelectedRtf = DirectCast(c, RichTextBox).Rtf
        End If

    Next
    temprtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test.rtf")
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Could you please choose it as your accepted answer if you are satisfied